# Polymer With Ember CLI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, polymer, handlebars.js

I am trying to access a paper-button inside a polymer component which is in a handlebars template in EMBER.

This is the Polymer component

```
    <link href="../polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link rel="import" href="../paper-button/paper-button.html">
<polymer-element name="my-new" noscript>
  <template>
    <paper-input></paper-input>
    <paper-button>BUTTON1</paper-button>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

This is my application.hbs

```
<my-new></my-new>
```

How to handle click event of the paper-button in the controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `action` helper

button

```
<paper-button {{action "doSomething"}}>BUTTON1</paper-button>
```

controller

```
Ember.Controller.extend({
 actions: {
   doSomething: function() {

   }
 }
})
```